# Azure AD v2 questions

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, azure-active-directory, adal

Working on a prototype Multitenant application. Building a Xamarin cross platform application using VS 2017. Questions below,

Can we use V1 end point with ADAL preview library ? VS 2017 portable project currently allow only the preview version of ADAL which is only looking for the V2 endpoints.

Look like V2 apps are multitenant aware by default unlike V1, is there a ways to restrict the different tenant and only subset of them ?

Answer (score 1):

When creating applications for the V1 Endpoint, you can use ADAL as a authentication library to simplify your code.

If you want to target the V2 Endpoint, you need to use a different library called MSAL. [Here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2017/P4031) is a solid video walking you through whats new in MSAL and the differences from ADAL.

Multi-tenancy in V2 is identical to multi-tenancy in V1. You are **not** able to restrict a multi-tenant application to a subset of tenants through the app configuration. Instead, you must adjust your application's code to check the issuer claim in the token and verify that the tenant matches the list you want to support.